# Jenkins Pipelines: Why is CPS Global Lib not loading?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm following the tutorial on the [pipeline library plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-global-lib-plugin/blob/master/README.md). I made a repository containing the following files:

```
D:.
│   Test.groovy
│   
├───src
└───vars
        helloWorld.groovy
```

helloWorld.groovy contains:

```
def call(name){
    echo "Hello world, ${name}"
}
```

Test.groovy contains:

```
helloWorld("Joe")
```

I installed all the pipeline plugins, in particular workflow-cps-global-lib-plugin. Then I created a new pipeline job in which I load this repository and set the Script Path to Test.groovy. When I run this job I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'helloWorld' found among [archive, bat, build, catchError, checkout, deleteDir, dir, echo, emailext, error, fileExists, git, input, isUnix, jiraComment, jiraIssueSelector, jiraSearch, load, mail, node, parallel, properties, pwd, readFile, readTrusted, retry, sh, sleep, stage, stash, step, svn, timeout, tool, unarchive, unstash, waitUntil, withEnv, wrap, writeFile, ws]
```

Why is the helloWorld step not defined? Here is my list of installed plugins: http://pastebin.com/xiMMub8J

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Pipeline Global Library expects a Git push event to update the Jenkins embedded workflow-libs git repo.

A push triggers the `UserDefinedGlobalVariableList.rebuild()` method see: https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-global-lib-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/global/UserDefinedGlobalVariableList.java

Here is a [groovy script](https://github.com/cloudbees/jenkins-scripts/blob/master/pipeline-global-lib-init.groovy) that pulls a GitHub repo into the Jenkins `workflow-libs` repos and then reloads it without a restart via:

`//Get Pipeline Global Library Jenkins Extension that rebuilds global library on Git Push
List extensions = ExtensionList.lookup(UserDefinedGlobalVariableList.class);
extensions.get(0).rebuild() //may want to add a check here to make sure extensions isn't null`

Comment: I had to fully qualify the UserDefinedGlobalVariableList, but then it worked great.
`List extensions = ExtensionList.lookup(org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.global.UserDefinedGlobalVariableList.class);
extensions.get(0).rebuild()`

Answer (score 1):

Using the 2.8 version of Pipeline:Groovy plugin I found that if I update the groovy scripts under /vars/myscript.groovy doesn't work, but if I **restart jenkins** everything works fine.
If I simply reload configuration from file, nothing happens.

So I think the scripts are instantiated as global functions only when jenkins start. (but maybe I'm wrong :) )

Comment: I updated to version 2.8, but unfortunately this did not fix my problem. Also restarting Jenkins every time when a pipeline script is pushed is not a viable solution for me, and I doubt this would work since if you look at the console output you can see the branch being checked out upon starting a build.

Comment: In my experience in the last days, if I add a new script.groovy in workflow-libs/vars/ I need to restart Jenkins to make it visible by a pipeline (just tried from a manually created pipeline script inside the web interface).
If I update a previous script the modify is present without restart jenkins. Don't ask me why, because I don't know. :)