# Jenkins Pipelines - Global library support cannot recognise vars

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

I have followed instructions from [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-global-lib-plugin) in order to add some global functions to my Jenkins Pipelines. I followed the directory structure provided and I load my code through an external git repository not the one provided by Jenkins itself. Although I can add some functions under src directory and are loaded correctly as explained, I cannot load the scripts added under vars directory. Is there any way to understand what is happening. My example groovy script is very simple:

```
// vars/hello.groovy
def call(name) {
    echo "Hello world, ${name}"
}
```

and i try to invoke it as follows

```
hello "foo"
```

I get the following:

```
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'hello' found among
> [archive, bat, build, catchError, checkout, deleteDir, dir, echo,
> error, fileExists, git, input, isUnix, load, mail, node, parallel,
> properties, pwd, readFile, retry, sh, sleep, stage, stash, step, svn,
> timeout, tool, unarchive, unstash, waitUntil, withEnv, wrap,
> writeFile, ws]    at
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:107)     at
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:113)
>   at groovy.lang.GroovyObject$invokeMethod.call(Unknown Source)   at
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
>   at
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
>   at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:151)
> 
> 
>
```

Has anyone faced any similar issue and how I can debug what is going on? 
My Jenkins version is: 1.625.2

**EDIT#1:**

After as well reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38073300/jenkins-pipelines-why-is-cps-global-lib-not-loading) indeed after a restart the script works, but this is not efficient to restart on each change. Is there any other solution to load the vars/*.groovy scripts without a restart?

Comment: You may want to check out the remote loader plugin (https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-remote-loader-plugin). My experience with it has been much better than the git based one.

Comment: Hi thank you for your comment, I have been using it in some cases, but my current status is to investigate the overmentioned way of putting you own DSL to jenkins

Comment: I think the answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38073300/jenkins-pipelines-why-is-cps-global-lib-not-loading