# How do I set up a Jenkins Pipeline global library using perforce as the SCM?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I've spent many hours on this without any success at all. According to [this](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-global-lib-plugin) I should be able to use any available SCM but I don't know how to map the paths, where, if anywhere, to insert the ${library.RegLib.version} or what workspace name to use.

I have a library set up as per the abovementioned docs:

```
<root>/src/org/somelib/MyLib.groovy
```

which contains:

```
package org.registration;

def doTest() {
    echo "test running..."
}
```

I've tried many different things but nothing works. I've also tried restarting Jenkins, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38073300/jenkins-pipelines-why-is-cps-global-lib-not-loading). No change.

My build reports:

```
Loading library MyLib@#1
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.p4.tasks.AbstractTask.setEnvironment(AbstractTask.java:106)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.p4.PerforceScm.checkout(PerforceScm.java:391)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:109)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.SCMSourceRetriever.doRetrieve(SCMSourceRetriever.java:107)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.SCMRetriever.retrieve(SCMRetriever.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.LibraryAdder.retrieve(LibraryAdder.java:150)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.LibraryAdder.add(LibraryAdder.java:131)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.LibraryDecorator$1.call(LibraryDecorator.java:99)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1053)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:591)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:569)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:546)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:67)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:429)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:392)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:221)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: Loading libraries failed
```

"Default version" is set to 1 because there's only been one commit. I've also tried #1. I don't know whether to map specific files or the top-level directory. If I remove the default version the build fails and complains that I haven't set a version. It's supposed to be optional but clearly isn't.

I've also tried using the vars directory

```
<root>/vars/doTest.groovy
```

which contains:

```
def call(msg) {
    echo msg
}
```

but I presume that also requires the library to be loaded. The docs are unclear about that.

So...

Will this work with perforce?

How do I map the paths to make it work?

How do I make the code in vars accessible? Is that loaded as part of the overall library?

Is there an error somewhere in my code?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reply to #HS10, I did and I've been meaning to update this for the benefit of others for ages but everything else in life seems to become higher priority. Since you've asked, here's what I did.

In Jenkins/Configuration, under Global Pipeline Libraries I set the following:

[image]

Specifically, provide a `Name` and set `Default version` to`head`. Set the `Retrieval method` to `Legacy SCM`. Perforce doesn't have Modeern SCM support, yet. Under `Source Code Management` select `Perforce Software`. Note that this is the `p4` plugin, not the old `Perforce` one which is listed as `Perforce`. I suspect that it's important to use the version written by Perforce themselves. Select a Credential that you have configured and provide a matching workspace name and mapping. I may have had that wrong earlier, I don't know. Other settings should be at your discretion. The library directory structure is as per the docs. I did think for a while that the workspace name had to be `_global_lib` but recent experiments appear to have disproved that.

In your pipeline, import the library like this:

```
@Library('plib') _

// do something
```

You should now have a working library.

I think I had this wrong earlier, as well. Note that the underscore is important. See the Global Lirary docs for more details. Getting this working caused me a lot of pain so I hope this saves someone from having a similar experience.

Answer (score 1):

Install [Pipeline Shared Libraries](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-global-lib-plugin) Plugin.

The configuration is in Manage Jenkins -> Global Pipeline Libraries

The retrieval method should be `legacy mode`. add repository

Tick the `Load implicitly` to load the scripts in every build

Put the groovy files in vars/yourGroovy.groovy and call it from Jenkinsfile:

```
yourGroovy()
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't answer any of the questions. It should be pretty clear that I've done that. Load `implicitly` is an option but I'm trying `@Library`.  Cheers.

Comment: I am able to access the vars/*.groovy files with just calling them from my Jenkinsfile. are you sure you configure the Global Pipeline Libraries settings correctly?

Comment: Obviously not, hence the questions. In fact I'm almost certain I'm not but nothing I've tried works.

Comment: look at the console output logs, look for 'Loading library <your-jenkins-files-repository>@master. if so - the configuration is ok. tell me if not and i'll try to walk you through the configuration

Comment: Thank you. I currently have the system settings set as mentioned: Name: Mylib, default version set to 1 and a perforce map like this ```//<prod>/trunk/src/apps/jenkinslib#${library.RegLib.version}/... //_global_lib/...``` where __global_lib is the workspace name and ```jenkinslib``` holds the library directory structure. I'm almost certain that's wrong but I've tried many other variations. I expect that it will work once I get the mapping right but it's got me stumped. The pipeline fails with the error shown in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an open issue with the p4 plugin, related to the p4 plugin being unable to deal with perforce checkouts at locations different from the workspace root:

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-40055

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-36243

Edit: You may be able to get this to work using older plugin versions, according to the reporter of the first issue:

> The crash is not present in version 2.4 of workflow-cps-global-lib, it
>   started to happen in version 2.5 only.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the first one does look particularly pertinent and I had been wondering whether this was possible at all. You might be right. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This is really late, but I was wondering if you found a solution.

In Amityo's answer you commented that your Perforce source path is `//<prod>/trunk/src/apps/jenkinslib#${library.RegLib.version}/...`, where `${library.RegLib.version} = 1` if no other version is explicitly specified in pipeline.

I think Jenkins will literally look for a folder named `jenkinslib#1`, which it won't find since your folder is just named `jenkinslib`.

I don't know how you would set up your structure to support different versions, but maybe having just `//<prod>/trunk/src/apps/jenkinslib/...` as your source path in the map might work, even though the config page tells you to add library.RegLib.version.

I would've commented all this on Amityo's post instead but I don't have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: Yes. See below.